# MS Exchange: Move meeting location

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, exchange-2007

We have two conference rooms with two users that have Full Access permissions to them. Is it possible for these two users to move meetings scheduled by other users from one conference room to another? Like bumping a meeting scheduled by a normal user from the large conference room to the small conference room.

Comment: The original event would have to be deleted and a new event created.  The two calendars are indepenent of one another.